# Java: Infinite loop hasNextInt()

Tags: java

ive tried looking up different sources on how to solve and my teacher is not very good at explaining so someone explain how to avoid the infinite loop because hasNext blocks further stuff idk. i would really appreicate it if someone would tell me how to do what i should do.

```
import java.util.*;

public class MergeSort{
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
    //declaring variables, files, and arrays
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    File file1 = new File("num1.txt");
    File file2 = new File("num2.txt");
    ArrayList<Integer> arr1 = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> arr2 = new ArrayList<>();

    //asking the amount of numbers
    System.out.print("How many numbers from file 1: ");
    int input1 = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.print("How many numbers from file 2: ");
    int input2 = scan.nextInt();

    // file 1
    try (Scanner s = new Scanner(file1)) {
      int i=0;
      while (s.hasNext()) {
        if (s.hasNextInt()) {
          if (i <= input1) {
            arr1.add(s.nextInt());
          }
        }
        i++;
      }
      System.out.println("i = " + i);
    } catch(Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Error");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think if you use File, you should "import java.io.File;"

Comment: Also you are not using your inputs. You do want to scan "input1" amount of ints from the first document, right? why not implement that somewhere. With the i++ you are incrementing i, but you are not checking if it has reached some threshold to get out of your loop.

Comment: if (i <= input1)
wouldnt this check?

Comment: You're still scanning the whole document. With || (or) and && (and) you can combine several terms and church them all in the same while or if statement

Comment: well how do i stop scanning the whole document?

Comment: You can add the statement into your while loop control. At the moment the loop body iterates as long as s.hasNext() is true. That means as long as there is something to read in the file. You can add another statement and once that's false the while loop will stop

Comment: ty. i figured it out